# jQuery dispatch event? How to

Tags: jquery, events, dispatch

how can i dispatch an event on my window ready?
For example in my code i've got:

```
$("#info").click(function(){
// do stuff
});
```

I need to call this function the first time without have a click on #info, in the way // do stuff.

Comment: Remember to click on the tick next to the answer that helps you.

Answer (score 13):

You could use the [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method:

```
$('#info').trigger('click');
```

or simply:

```
$('#info').click();
```

which would be the same.

Comment: Avoid unnecessary event chaining.  If the app is complex it WILL mess you up eventually.  This event will bubble all the way down the DOM and can cause issues with other functionality.  If you just want to run the method on document ready then just run it on document ready.  If you need to give it a context just use apply. I'm going to down vote this just because the below answer is dead on.

Comment: how about click with CTRL using this trigger?

Answer (score 11):

A better way might be to make a function that does the required stuff, then do `$(document).ready(myFunc);` and `$("#info").click(myFunc);`.

Comment: Big +1 People seem to think they can abandon proper design just because it's a web app.

Comment: @T.J. - if the function's written with the context being the button though, it may be much easier and less code to trigger the event.

Comment: @Nick: If the code is meant to run in multiple contexts (not just in response to a button click), then it should be its own function and *called* from multiple locations. I'm not at all sure using `click` to trigger it is "easier" but even if it were, IMHO it's not a good idea. (People **have** been known to disagree with me, from time to time. ;-) )

Comment: @Nick - You're right, it depends on the situation. But we've got two useful answers here so everyone's a winner :)

Comment: By far a better answer.  Some people don't understand that its easy to make an anonymous function a named function.  Avoiding unnecessary event chaining will save you many headaches.  If you need to change the context just use apply invocation.